# Create multiple foreign keys on the same table in migrate laravel

Tags: laravel-4

```
    Schema::table('performance', function($table)
    {
        $table->foreign('song_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('songs')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
    Schema::table('performance', function($table)
    {
        $talbe->foreign('artist_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('artists')
                ->onDelete('cascade');  
    });
```

I got an error: **"Call to a member function foreign() on a non-object"** .

Answer (score 5):

You can't use multiple commands for foreign keys, instead. You only need one foreign key command and combine all rows you wish to define. Here is the code you should run.

```
Schema::table('performance', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->unsignedInteger('song_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('artist_id');
            $table->foreign(['song_id','artist_id'])->references(['id','id'])
                  ->on(['song','artists'])->onDelete(['cascade','cascade']);
        });
```

If it doesn't work (previous Laravel versions may not work), we can use common SQL statement to add other foreign keys.

```
Schema::table('performance', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->unsignedInteger('song_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('artist_id');
            $table->foreign('song_id')->references('id')
                  ->on('song')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
DB::statement(
    "ALTER TABLE performance ADD FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artists(id) ON DELETE CASCADE"
);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Achmad. You need to use array for define multiple columns. Ex. $table->foreign(['song_id','artist_id'])->references(['id','id'])...

Comment: @ahmeti thanks for the correction. It did work at the time I wrote the answer, but it might not for the next updates.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Achmad. I did NOT check old laravel versions. But, i am sure not working laravel 5.6. Thank you for your tricks :)

Comment: you can use multiple `->foreign()` with `Schema::create`... not sure what the difference is with `Schema::table`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the object name from *`$talbe`* to `$table`

```
          Schema::table('performance', function (Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->foreign('song_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('songs')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->foreign('artist_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('artists')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            });
```

**Edit: Updated! for your code $table should be the instance of Blueprint class. So that could be the cause for this problem!**

Comment: I think it's not problem we got in here.

Comment: I added Blueprint class before $table parameter of function. But it also get the same problem.

Comment: @KarthiSkb how i drop both foreign keys with table??